# Reading from closed NetworkStream doesn't cause any exception

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a rather simple client-server application, but for communication I want to use binary serialized objects. The communication itself seems rather fine, but when I close the stream on the client's side, the server doesn't really notice it and keeps on trying to read the stream.

server side (class Server, executed in separate thread):

listening for connections

```
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), this.Port);
listener.Start();
while (!interrupted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    AddClient(client);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
}
```

adding the client:

```
    public void AddClient(TcpClient socket)
    {
        Client client = new Client(this, socket);
        this.clients.Add(client);
        client.Start();
    }
```

listening for messages (deep inside Client class):

```
BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
while (!interrupted)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for the message...");
    AbstractMessage msg = (AbstractMessage)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message arrived: " + msg.GetType());
    raiseEvent(msg);
}
```

unit test:

```
Server server = new Server(6666);
server.Start();

Thread.Sleep(500);

TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6666);
var message = new IntroductionMessage();
byte[] arr = message.Serialize();

client.GetStream().Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);

Thread.Sleep(500);

Assert.AreEqual(1, server.Clients.Count);

client.GetStream().Close();
client.Close();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

Assert.AreEqual(0, server.Clients.Count);

server.Stop();
```

so the message gets read properly, but then, when I close the stream, deserializer.Deserialize(stream) doesn't appear to throw any exceptions... so should it just not be read this way, or should I close the client in a different way?

Comment: Where does the server gets the stream from? A TcpListener instance inside the Server object?

Comment: now, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the stream used in the Server for deserializing the message is a [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) (which is the type of the stream returned by *TcpClient.GetStream()*), you should do two things:

1. Define a specific message for "connection ends". When the server receives and deserializes this message, exit the while-loop. To make this work, the client obviously needs to send such a message before closing its TcpClient connection. (You might choose a different mechanism working in a similar manner -- but why not using the message mechanism you already have in place...)
2. Set a **ReadTimeout** on the *NetworkStream*, so in case the connection gets lost and the client is unable to send a "connection ends" message, the server will hit the timeout and realize that the client is "dead".

The code in your server for listening to client messages should look similar to this:

```
//
// Time-out after 1 minute after receiving last message
//
stream.ReadTimeOut = 60 * 1000;

BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();

try
{
    while (!interrupted)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for the message...");
        AbstractMessage msg = (AbstractMessage)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message arrived: " + msg.GetType());

        //
        // Exit while-loop when receiving a "Connection ends"  message.
        // Adapt this if condition to whatever is appropriate for
        // your AbstractMessage type.
        //
        if (msg == ConnectionEndsMessage) break;

        raiseEvent(msg);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    ... handle timeout and other IOExceptions here...
}
```

Comment: @Kamil: Depending on the raw size of the messages and the (network) environment in which your software is being used, you will have to choose a rather large timeout (to cater for crappy hotel internet connections or perhaps even crusty modem connection, ahem...). In my example, i have chosen a one minute timout. If your program only runs in a LAN (or on low-latency internet connections), you might choose a timeout of less than 30 seconds.

Comment: In any case, do not rely on timeouts alone and implement a dedicated "Connection Ends" message. That will help you tremendously in troubleshooting problems where it is not clear whether the issue is a bug in your client or server, or whether it is an issue with the internet/network connection...